# arcpy CSV file to raster attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, raster, esri-geodatabase, attribute-table

Using `TableToTable_conversion` I can convert a CSV file to a table in a geodatabase, but how can make this table be the default attribute table for a raster in the geodatabase?

I can't seem to find anything on this...

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you're looking for:
[Joining tables to your raster attribute table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t00000060000000) 
See also:
[Essentials of Joining Tables](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002p000000)

A second probably more difficult option is to manipulate your CSV file to match Arc's ASCII raster format and then use [ASCII to Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000002s000000) to create a new raster that perfectly overlays your target raster, then [Combine](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000083000000.htm) those two rasters.